# I Have Database Errors on my Codeigniter script

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

i install a school management system and one time login but after logout and enter username and password show a box with this message:

> A Database Error Occurred , You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `_id` IS NULL' at line 2 . SELECT * WHERE `_id` IS NULL . Filename: views/backend/header.php . Line Number: 34 "

header.php code :

```css
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 clearfix" style="text-align:center;">
     <h2 style="font-weight:200; margin:0px;"><?php echo $system_name;?></h2>
    </div>
    <!-- Raw Links -->
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 clearfix ">

        <ul class="list-inline links-list pull-left">
        <!-- Language Selector -->
            <div id="session_static">
             <li>
                 <h4>
                     <a href="#" style="color: #696969;"
 <?php if($account_type == 'admin'):?>
                    onclick="get_session_changer()"
 <?php endif;?>>
 <?php echo get_phrase('running_session');?> : <?php echo $running_year.' ';?><i class="entypo-down-dir"></i>
                  </a>
                 </h4>
             </li>
            </div>
        </ul>


  <ul class="list-inline links-list pull-right">

  <li class="dropdown language-selector">
   <a href="<?php echo site_url('home');?>" target="_blank">
    <i class="entypo-globe"></i> Website
   </a>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-close-others="true">
                         <i class="entypo-user"></i>
             <?php
              $name = $this->db->get_where($this->session->userdata('login_type'), array($this->session->userdata('login_type').'_id' => $this->session->userdata('login_user_id')))->row()->name;
              echo $name;
             ?>
                    </a>

    <?php if ($account_type != 'parent'):?>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu <?php if ($text_align == 'right-to-left') echo 'pull-right'; else echo 'pull-left';?>">
     <li>
      <a href="<?php echo site_url($account_type . '/manage_profile');?>">
                         <i class="entypo-info"></i>
       <span><?php echo get_phrase('edit_profile');?></span>
      </a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="<?php echo site_url($account_type . '/manage_profile');?>">
                         <i class="entypo-key"></i>
       <span><?php echo get_phrase('change_password');?></span>
      </a>
     </li>
    </ul>
    <?php endif;?>
    <?php if ($account_type == 'parent'):?>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu <?php if ($text_align == 'right-to-left') echo 'pull-right'; else echo 'pull-left';?>">
     <li>
      <a href="<?php echo site_url('parents/manage_profile');?>">
                         <i class="entypo-info"></i>
       <span><?php echo get_phrase('edit_profile');?></span>
      </a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="<?php echo site_url('parents/manage_profile');?>">
                         <i class="entypo-key"></i>
       <span><?php echo get_phrase('change_password');?></span>
      </a>
     </li>
    </ul>
    <?php endif;?>
   </li>

   <li>
    <a href="<?php echo site_url('login/logout');?>">
     <?php echo get_phrase('log_out'); ?><i class="entypo-logout right"></i>
    </a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>

</div>

<hr style="margin-top:0px;" />

<script type="text/javascript">
 function get_session_changer()
 {
  $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo site_url('admin/get_session_changer');?>',
            success: function(response)
            {
                jQuery('#session_static').html(response);
            }
        });
 }
</script>
```

line 34 :

```html
$name = $this->db->get_where($this->session->userdata('login_type'), array($this->session->userdata('login_type').'_id' => $this->session->userdata('login_user_id')))->row()->name;
```

I am beginner . please help me step by step

Comment: It looks like you have shown us the wrong code. I dont see that query anywhere in this code

Comment: If you notice `_id` should be `something_id` by your code. the part that generates `something` e.g. `$this->session->userdata('login_type')` is not set. hence your error. find out why and it should fix your issue.

Comment: this script is ekattor school management . i have a backup of database and can give permission to access to my host.